# Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in /project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:721

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When I try to run my Laravel project by using

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

or

```
php artisan serve
```

it throws this error log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:721
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(721): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(600): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(567): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(246): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Kernel', Array)
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(718): Ill in /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 721
```

I have tried deleting vendor folder and reinstalling through composer by using this command

```
composer install
```

but it didn't work. I have tried to debug and tried all the possible solutions available on this platform but I was unable to resolve the error. 
I have tried these commands as well

```
 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan cache:clear
 composer update
 composer dump-autoload
```

but unfortunetly none of them worked. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is the Kernel being bound in /bootstrap/app.php?

Comment: $app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

Yes, it is... @RobertAguilar

Answer (score -1):

First of all, does `App\Http\Kernel.php` exist?

Second, does it get bound to the service container in `bootstrap\app.php`?

It should look like this:

```php
// ...Line 28
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
// Line 43...
```

Comment: Yes, it does exist and My code looks the same as yours.

Answer (score -1):

I also did run into class App\Http\Kernel.php not found.

Didn't know how but it happens that my  http folder had been moved to my project directory.

A simple copy of the \Http\ folder and pasting into the App folder resolved the issue